# Create a slider using web part which will have cover images

Tags: sharepoint

I need to create a slider using a web part in share point office 365, I am new to sharepoint is there any ways to achieve it using native Sharepoint webparts

Answer (score 0):

You've not really given much information.

This slider is on the app store might be of some use.

https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/WA104379257?tab=Overview

Cheers

Truez